# Resetting scroll to top when clicking Home link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am setting up a web page.  I am not a programmer but have been able to navigate through it with a reasonable amount of success.  My problem is this - I have a portion of a web page ( a Div) that has scrollable text using the Overflow property.  I am able to have the text return to the top with an anchor link to the top of the page, however when I click the link I have set up to return to "Home" it does so but does not reset the scroll bar to the top.  Can someone tell me how to enable the page so I can click "Home" AND have it reset the scrollbar to the top?  Thanks.

Here is the code I am using.

Anchor to top of page =

```
<a name="pgtop"></a>
```

Div referencing the anchor including styling =

```
<div class="rtop"><a href="#pgtop">Return To Top</a></div>
```

Link at bottom of page selecting "Home" - pretty standard stuff =

```
<div class="footerlinks"><a href="#">Home</a></div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like the code is missing.

Comment: where is your code??we can't help you with your problem if we don't see your effort until now

Comment: I entered it but it doesn't display.  Any ideas?

Comment: You haven't formated your code. I think someone else is doing it now.

Comment: Please post your CSS as well or a JSFiddle would be great

Comment: in your link at the bottom href = `#` means this pages top (it won't slide your divs scroll) ...try `?` to reload the page or `http://www.your-webpage-home-url.com` ;)

Comment: when you enter your code, the menu at the top of your question have this "{}" so you have to paint all your code part and press this button

Comment: You are going to need to use some Javascript to accomplish this. Using an `anchor name` tag will only take you to the div that it's linked to, it won't scroll the content within a div.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a javascript click function to your link. Note my link in this sample called "scroll up". It calls a function called "scrollUp()". That function grabs your div by ID and sets the scroll to the top.

Simply add this script to your page and change the ID to match the ID of your div. Then add an "OnClick" to your anchor link. I edited the answer to match the code you posted.

```
<html>
     <head>
          <style type="text/css">
          div.rtop {
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            overflow:scroll;
           }
          </style>
     </head>
    <body>
        <a name="pgtop"></a>
        <div class="rtop" id="somediv">You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible.
            <a href="#pgtop" onClick="scrollUp()">Return To Top</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
function scrollUp(){
    var myDiv = document.getElementById('somediv');
    myDiv.scrollTop = 0;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: no problem. Please let us know if this is what you are looking for and if the answer was correct. Or if you were trying to do what webdev-dan  suggested.

Answer (score 1):

as i mentioned in the comment:

in your link at the bottom `href="#"` means current pages top (it won't slide your divs scroll - only documents scroll) 
...try `href="?"` to reload current page or `href="http://url.to.your.home.page"` to put a link that loads your homepage if your current page is not a homepage which you want to navigate to.

here is some referencing document if you want to learn more

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Answer (score -1):

just add this jquery and you are done.

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("pgtop").offset().top
}, 2000);
```

Comment: It's good to add some explanation to your code describing what it does.